# Partial derivative of cross-entropy

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, entropy, neural-networks

I am trying to make sense of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/235528/224903).

$$E(t,o)=-\sum_j t_j \log o_j$$

How did he derive the following?

$$\frac{\partial E} {\partial o_j} = \frac{-t_j}{o_j}$$

Comment: This is just the partial with respect to o for element j.

Comment: @chris Yeah I just figured it out, it is actually extremely easy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP wrote that it is "extremely easy" to see that the partial derivative of $E(t,o)=-\sum_j t_j \log o_j$ w.r.t. $o_j$ is $-t_j/o_j.$ There was no further question.

Answer (score 0):

I think "he" is assuming that the $t_i$, $o_i$ are *independent variables*; then they are each *constant*, any one with respect to any other; we have:

$\dfrac{\partial t_i}{\partial o_j} = 0, \forall i, \; j, \tag 1$

$\dfrac{\partial o_i}{\partial o_j} = 0, \forall i, \; j, \; i \ne j,\tag 2$

$\dfrac{\partial o_i}{\partial o_i} = 1, \forall i; \tag 3$

applying formulas (1)-(3) to

$E(t, o) = -\displaystyle \sum_j t_j \ln o_j \tag 4$

yields

$\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial o_i} = -\displaystyle \sum_j \dfrac{\partial (t_j \ln o_j)}{\partial o_i} = -\sum_j t_j \dfrac{\partial \ln o_j}{\partial o_i} =  -\dfrac{t_i}{o_i}, \; \forall i; \tag 5$

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a reformulation Christopher Bishop (1995) took for the cross-entropy, because the formulation

\begin{equation}
E=-\sum_j t_j \log (y_j)
\end{equation}

does not have a minimum value of zero.

However, his reformulation below for cross-entropy error has a minimum value of zero:

\begin{equation}
E=-\sum_j t_j \log \left( \frac{y_j}{t_j} \right).
\end{equation}

For the above equation, the partial derivative of the error $E$ w.r.t $y_j$ is simply

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial y_j}=-\frac{t_j}{y_j} .
\end{equation}

Comment: While this could be true the (non)negativity was not OP's problem.

Comment: @Kurt G - thanks for the comment.  But isn't the OP asking where that partial derivative came from?  In the original link in the OP, the author simply stated that $\partial E/ \partial o_j$ is $-t_j/o_j$.  In the citation I provided (Bishop, 1995), that partial derivative, $-t_j/o_j$, is given for the normalized variant of error, $E=-\sum t_j \log(o_j/t_j)$, not the non-normalized.  In fact, for cross-entropy, Bishop doesn't provide a partial derivative for $E=-\sum t_j \log(o_j)$

Comment: See my close vote of the original post now. I don't get what else OP was asking.